Invisible Clouds In my render viewport and my Rendered Frame
Im a intern that has recently been giving the task of making a logo animation for the company. Now im nearly finished and recently followed a toturial in order to make the clouds that my camera is going to fly trough, However, When I went to check how it looked in my render/viewport I saw a problem.
In my rendered viewport and when I rendered a single frame, (trough 12) I noticed the lack of clouds that I had made. They just don't show up. Im pretty new to blender and this whole process has had its up and downs, But this specific problem gave me the feeling that the awnser to my problem lies in experiance and knowledge. Im lacking in both of those.
Here is the clouds GeometryNodes:
Here are my material settings. (ive opened up the volume one since my gut says that the problem lies somewhere in there):

The Solid viewport:

My material viewport:

My Render viewport:

My rendered frame:

My Render Settings:

Let me know if there are any more screenshots you would like to have or any other information you would like to know. I would be happy to help you help me
My Thanks in advance



The volumetric material is a custom built shader node which does not come with Blender. How should we know how it works on the inside? We need to see the nodetree of the material or you upload the file to https://blend-exchange.com (although this might be problematic if this is from your company).

@GordonBrinkmann  Thank you for your comment, Ive added a screenshot of my shading tab of the material (all the way down below). Let me know if there is anything else you want to know or if you see the problem.
Thanks

As GordonBrinkmann said, we can't guess how this Procedural Clouds node works. We'd need either to see the full node tree inside Procedural Clouds, or the blend files. The blend file is a must if you hope to get an answer.

@Lutzi Thank you for your answer. I am still trying to get permission to share the file for help. However, as long as that permission is not given, my hands will be tied. Hopefully, that will change in the near future. However, from both comments, I assume that the problem lies with the material preset I used. So I'll be searching for a solution in other preset materials. Sharing the full node tree of that material is what I did in the last screenshot of the slide. That is all this material has as a node tree. (Unless the shading tab is not the node tree of a material but I think it is?!

What happens if you set volume cutoff to 0 and bump the density multiplier up to like 100?

@IncentroScout The "Procedural Clouds" is a custom made nodegroup, so it is not a single node like the original ones that come with Blender. Instead you can "open" it by selecting it and pressing Tab (just like switching between Object Mode and Edit Mode on mesh objects) to reveal the inner setup of the nodetree. Although from my experience those custom nodegroups sometimes contain even more custom nodegroups so there might be a large hierarchy to be expanded...

@TheJeran Interesting Idea but sadly it had no effect, Thanks for you suggestion!

@GordonBrinkmann Thank you for the extra explanation. Always fun to learn new things. I've added a screenshot of the connected node of the material (but this time the fully extended node tree that was hidden within). Let me know if this helps or if you want to know anything else (or if the screenshot is to small to read). I checked if there were multiple layers but that screenshot is as deep as it goes.
